# Left join statement returning unexpected null values for rows/column that have data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I have two tables that I'm writing a query against. Some of the columns can be found in one of the tables, while some of the columns are calucalted.

For clarity, I will copy my query below:

```
select field_a,
       cast(field_b as int),
       field_c,
       field_d,
       Year,
       coalesce( cast(field_e as float),0) America_spend,
       sum( cast(field_e as float), 0) as America_spend,
       coalesce( cast(field_e as float)/ sum( cast( field_e as float)) over(partition by Year) as total_spend
from table_a
left join table_b on
    table_a.flield_a = table_b.field_a1 and 
    table_a.flield_b = table_b.field_b1 and 
    table_a.Year = table_b.Year
group by field_a,
         field_b,
         Year
```

I have tables that look like this

table a:

```
|field_a|field_b|field_c|field_d|Year|field_f|field_g|field_h
|data   |   1   | data  |  data |2014| data  | data  | data
|data   |   1   | data  |  data |2014| null  | data  | data
|0      |   1   | data  |  data |2014| data  | data  | data
|data   |   1   | data  |  data |2014| null  | data  | data
|0      |   1   | data  |  data |2014| data  | data  | data
```

table b:

```
|field_a1|field_b1|Year|field_c1|field_j
|null    |   1   |2014| data   | data
|data    |   1   |2015| data   | data
|null    |   0   |2014| data   | data
|data    |   1   |2015| data   | data
|null    |   0   |2014| data   | data
```

The problem that I'm having is that some of the values in the 'total spend column' get assigned a value of null. Total spend is calculated per year and this field should never be null. Likewise, the year column doesn't contain a null value in either of the tables. But for some reason when I run the query, I get results that have some of the rows in the year column with a null value. This should never happen. Most of the results conform to what I would expect, but there are some that do not.

I'm guessing that is has something to do with the fact that some of the rows in field_b are null and get converted to 0, but why does this matter?

I updated the tables and the queries to more accurately reflect the structure of the database.

Yes the query runs and I have no naming conflicts.

Comment: Does that query really execute?

Comment: @jarlh The query executes, I'm just getting results that I wasn't expecting.

Comment: Well when you have NULL the join will not return a matched row because NULL <> NULL. Not sure why you are casting to floats. You should probably use a numeric instead as floats are approximate. As posted this query would not execute because not all of the columns are either in the group by or aggregated.

Comment: 1. You should use aliases for your tables, since for example your grouping contains an ambiguous column name. 2. Which value are you expecting from field_c and field_e? Since you're not grouping by them at all.

Comment: I could expect MySQL to execute that query, but SQL Server??? (The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.")

Comment: Also, there are some possible typing errors. And ambiguous column names... That query can never execute!

Comment: @SeanLange I'm casting as float because of how I imported the data. Some of the data in the file that I used really was text that contained foreign characters, some was numeric. I just imported everything as text and then convert what I need to the appropriate data type. I'll edit  the query to include more details. There are a lot of columns between the two tables so I tried to abbreviate things. With that being said, the query runs on my computer and most of the results do what I expect. But some of the results don't make sense.

Comment: You simplified this so much that you lost the problem. As posted, that query will not execute. It has column names typed wrong, missing aggregates/group by, a coalesce with only 1 argument. This query is obviously part of an actual query but this just isn't going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SeanLange's comment is what is most likely the issue with your expected results.  That is that `NULL` does NOT Equal `NULL` (`NULL <> NULL`).  `Null` is an "`unknown`" value in sql and 2 unknowns are not equal.

But you can eliminate your NULL if you want to match them together as the same case.  Simply use `COALESCE()` or `ISNULL()` and provide the same default value on both sides of your ON condition and make sure your default is not represented within your dataset or you will get undesired results.

```
DECLARE @TableA AS TABLE (FieldA VARCHAR(5),FiledB INT,Yr INT)
DECLARE @TableB AS TABLE (FieldA VARCHAR(5),FiledC INT,Yr INT)

INSERT INTO @TableA (FieldA,FiledB,Yr)
VALUES (null,1,2014),('data',1,2015),(null,1,2014),('data',1,2015),(null,1,2014)
INSERT INTO @TableB (FieldA,FiledC,Yr)
VALUES (null,1,2014),('data',1,2015),(null,1,2014),('data',1,2015),(null,1,2014)

SELECT *
FROM
    @TableA a
    LEFT JOIN @TableB b
    ON COALESCE(a.FieldA,'NULLVALUE') = COALESCE(b.FieldA,'NULLVALUE')
    AND a.Yr = b.Yr
```

Your particular example dataset that you provided us repeats FieldA to Yr Combinations so the results are a little funky but it still works.